# How exactly do I use Lightning Network? Does it even actually exist?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-rfc

http://lightning.network/how-it-works/

Where is the download button for the official, highly trusted CLI application which works with Bitcoin Core? So that I can actually make Lightning transactions?

I've spent so long trying to figure out how to actually use this thing. I can't have the current large fees for my products/services which are the same amount as the fee. That's why I need to support Lightning Network. But how? Why is there no information?

Comment: There is no ‘official’ anything in bitcoin. There are several implementations of lightning network nodes to choose from if you want to participate in the network though.

Answer (score 6):

If you recommend ["Mastering the Lightning Network" in chapter 2](https://github.com/lnbook/lnbook/blob/develop/02_getting_started.asciidoc) you find a table of possible Lightning Network implementations:

| Application | Device | Lightning Node | Bitcoin Node | Keystore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eclair Mobile | Mobile | Lightweight | Electrum | Self-Custody |
| Breez Wallet | Mobile | Full Node | Neutrino | Self-Custody |
| Phoenix Wallet | Mobile | Lightweight | Electrum | Self-Custody |
| Zeus | Mobile | Full Node | Bitcoin Core/btcd | Self-Custody |
| lntxbot | Mobile | None | None | Custodial |
| Blue Wallet | Mobile | None | None | Custodial |
| Muun | Mobile | None | None | Self-Custody |
| Zap Desktop | Desktop | Full Node | Neutrino | Self-Custody |
| Electrum | Desktop | Full Node | Bitcoin Core/Electrum | Self-Custody |
| lnd | Server | Full Node | Bitcoin Core/btcd | Self-Custody |
| c-lightning | Server | Full Node | Bitcoin Core | Self-Custody |
| Eclair Server | Server | Full Node | Bitcoin Core/Electrum | Self-Custody |

just select from there whatever suits you best

I think the two most popular implementations are [c-lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning) and [lnd](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how advance your understandig is, you can either set up your own LN node or use clients, which are extremely easy to use. At the beginning, I recommend Breez mobile wallet as it opens up a LN channel for you.

Comment: How do I "set up my own LN node"? That's what I'm asking. "Mobile wallet"? What?