# clients that support the Lightning Network?

Tags: client, lightning-network

Which clients, besides [Electrum](https://electrum.org/), support the [Lightning Network](https://lightning.network/)?

Comment: @TonySanak No, here I'm asking about clients implementing the Lightning Network implementation.

Comment: What about this one? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102528/how-exactly-do-i-use-lightning-network-does-it-even-actually-exist/102533#102533